# Multi-reader IPC solution?

Tags: c++, ipc

I'm working on a framework in C++ (just for fun for now), that lets the user write plugins that use a standard API to stream data between each other.  There's going to be three basic transport mechanisms for the data: files, sockets, and some kind of IPC piping system.  The system is set up so that for the non-file transport, each stream can have multiple readers. IE once a server socket it setup, multiple computers can connect and stream the data.  I'm a little stuck at the multi-reader IPC system though.

All my plugins run in threads (though I may want to go to a process-based system eventually) so they live in the same address space, so some kind of shared memory system would work fine, I was thinking I'd write my own circular buffer with a write pointer and read pointers chassing it around the buffer, but I have my doubts that I can achieve the same performance as something like linux pipes.

I'm curious what people would suggest for a multi-reader solution to something like this?  Is the overhead for pipes or domain sockets low enough that I could just open a connection to each reader and issue separate writes to each reader?  This is intended to be significant volumes of data (tens of mega-samples/sec), so performance is a must.

Comment: For the network part have you considered using IP multicast?

Comment: That's definitely something that's on the menu for version 2.0, but I wanted to focus on basic functionality for now

Answer (score 0):

I develop a media server, and i usually use a single reader for a group of all active sockets of the same class. You can use a select() (in a blocking or non blocking mode) function for each group to read the sockets that became ready to be read. When a socket data is ready or a new connection occur i just call a notify callback function to manage it.

Each reader (that controls a group of sockets) could be managed by a separate thread, avoiding your main threads to block while waiting for new connections or socket data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the description correctly, it seems to me that using a circular queue as you mention would be a good IPC solution. I think it could scale very well and would ultimately be better than individual pipes or individual shared memory for each client. One (of several) of the issues of using a single queue/buffer for multiple clients is to synchronize access to the buffers. A client needs to be able to successfully read an entry in the queue without the server changing it. Here is a possible mechanism for implementing that.

This requires that the server know how many active clients there are. That, I assume, would be possible as long as the clients are doing some kind of registration/login with the server (almost certainly true if they are in-process but not necessarily true for out-of-process clients).

- Suppose there are N clients. For this example, assume 100 active clients.
- Maintain two counting semaphores for each entry in the circular queue. If using out-of-process clients, these need to be shared between processes. Call the semaphores SemReady and SemDone.
- Use SemReady to indicate that the buffer is ready for clients to read. The server writes to the buffer entry and then sets the value of the semaphore to the number of clients (100 in this case). More on this in a bit.
- When a client wants to read an entry in the queue, it waits on the associated SemReady semaphore.  If the initial value is at 100, then all 100 clients can successfully get the semaphore and “concurrently” read the data.
- When a client is done reading/using the entry, it increments/releases the SemDone semaphore.
- When a server wants to write to a buffer entry, it needs to make sure of two things: a) no clients are currently reading it, and b) no clients start to read it once the server is writing to it.
- Therefore, first, block any further access to the buffer by waiting on the SemReady semaphore until the count is zero (obviously, use a zero timeout). When it hits zero, the server knows that no additional clients will start reading it.
- To know that clients are done with the buffer, the server uses the SemDone semaphore. It checks the SemDone and waits until it is at value is at N *minus* the number of waits it did on SemReady. In other words, if SemReady was at zero, then it means all clients read the buffer entry, therefore, SemDone should be at N (100) when they are done. If, though, the server waited 10 times on SemReady, then SemDone should be at 90 (N-10) when all clients are done.
- The above step needs some kind of timeout and status check on client “liveness” in case a client crashes/quits after getting SemReady and before releasing SemDone.  Also, it would need to account for the possibility of new client registering during that step as well in order to keep the semaphore count values in sync.
- Once the server has found no more clients are reading the buffer, it can reset SemDone to zero, write new data to the entry, and set SemReady to N (100).
- Rinse and repeat.

**Note 1** There are other synchronization issues to maintain the head/tail of the circular queue so that clients know where it is.

**Note 2** SemDone could probably be an integer counter handled with atomic increments… I think it could anyway.  Needs a bit of thought.

**Note 3** It might make sense to have multiple threads in the server writing to the buffer entries. That way, if the server has to wait/timeout a bit on a crashed client that started reading but did not finish, it would not block subsequent queue entries that other clients might already be waiting for.